# Prove that a perfect square is not a primitive root modulo $p$ for any prime $p>3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Assume $a=-1$ or that $a$ is a perfect square. Prove that $a$ is not a primitive root modulo $p$ for any prime $p>3$.

Let $p>3$ be an arbitrary prime. First, we assume $a$ is a perfect square. Write $a=b^2$. Then $a^{\phi(p)/2}=b^{\phi(p)}$. How do I know that $\gcd(b,p)=1$ here? (Because $b=1,2,3,\dots$, so $b$ and $p$ must have some common factor). Anyway, if this is true, we would then get $b^{\phi(p)}\equiv 1\pmod p$, which makes $a$ not to be a primitive root modulo $p$. This case is done. For the other case, I have no clue where to begin.

Comment: If $a$ is a perfect square then so is every power of $a$.

Comment: @lulu You mean $a^n=(b^2)^n = (b^n)^2$ for all $n$?

Comment: If $a=-1$, the order of $a$, mod $p$, is $2$.

Comment: @quasi Right ... $(-1)^2=1\equiv 1\pmod p$. But then we must have $2=\phi(p)$, which is only valid when $p=3$. Since $p>3$, it can not be a primitive root modulo $p$. Am I right on this?

Comment: @Hopeless: Simpler than that. The set of powers of $-1$, mod $p$, has cardinality $2$, which is less than $p-1$, since $p > 3$.

Comment: @quasi Thank you, that's smart. If you have time, could you please help me for the other case? Any hints ...

Comment: @Hopeless: Use lulu's hint. If $a$ is a perfect square, and also a primitive root, then all powers of $a$ are quadratic residues, mod $p$. But how many quadratic residues are there, mod $p$?

Comment: @quasi I see. Unfortunately, I haven't reached the concept of quadratic residues yet... I want to make sure if I understand you correctly, you are saying, if $a$ is a perfect square and a primitive root modulo $p$, then $x^2\equiv a^n\pmod p$ is solvable for all  $n$?

Comment: @Hopeless: The point is that if $S=\{0,...,p−1\}$, the map $f:S\to S$ given by $f(x)=(x^2\;\text{mod}\;p)$, is not injective (since for example, $f(p−1)=f(1))$, hence, since $S$ is finite, $f$ is not surjective. Thus, not every element of $S$ is a square, mod $p$. But as lulu hinted, if $a$ is a perfect square, then all powers of $a$ are squares, mod $p$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g$ be a primitive root mod $p$. Write $b=g^n$. Then $a=g^{2n}$, which has order $$\dfrac{p-1}{\gcd(2n,p-1)} \le \dfrac{p-1}{2} < p-1$$
Thus, $a$ cannot be a primitive root mod $p$.

Comment: Why do you choose $g$ to be primitive rood moulo $p$? What if $g$ were not this one?

Comment: @Hopeless, it does not matter which primitive root we choose.

Comment: I wasn't thinking straight on the first comment. What I meant is, why did you choose to *let* $g$ be a primitive root modulo $p$. Would you reach another same conclusion if $g$ were *assumed* to be non-primitive modulo $p$?